# Error running transactions on HANA database

Tags: database, multithreading, transactions, hana, bulk

I am running bulk transactions on HANA database and getting following error:

```
2018-01-15 10:23:33,865 ERROR c.c.t.Payment [tpcc-thread-5] UPDATE district SET d_ytd = d_ytd + 1601.0 WHERE d_w_id = 1 AND d_id = 1
com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [138]: transaction serialization failure: TrexUpdate failed on table 'SYSTEM:DISTRICT' with error: transaction order error, rc=4614
at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB._newInstance(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:193)
.......
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-01-15 10:23:34,139 ERROR c.c.t.Payment [tpcc-thread-5] Payment error
java.lang.Exception: Payment update transaction error
```

Anybody has any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you using the same connection by multiple threads via HANA JDBC driver? If so, you might want to try using a single connection per thread. Other than that, please post the minimal command sequence that leads to the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that this was a valid error. For transaction type REPEATABLE_READ or SERIALIZABLE this problem can occur when before end of one transaction, another transaction modifies the same data which transaction one was working on.

To get rid of this error, we can use transaction type READ_COMMITTED, which takes a snapshot of the data at the beginning and uses the same data throughout the transaction. It will also lock the rows its working on so that other transactions cannot modify it.